# Can't install nuget package because of “Failed to initialize the PowerShell host”

Tags: powershell, visual-studio-2015, nuget, nuget-package, nuget-package-restore

Can't install nuget package because of “Failed to initialize the PowerShell host”
This is the Error The following error occurred while loading the extended type data file: 
, C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2ZQ00DAJ.XOI\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.Types.ps1xml: The file was skipped because of the following validation exception: File C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\2ZQ00DAJ.XOI\Modules\NuGet\NuGet.Types.ps1xml cannot be loaded because its operation is blocked by software restriction policies, such as those created by using Group Policy..

Comment: This question is off topic. However, configure the `Turn On Script Execution` setting within your Group Policy...

Answer (score -1):

Since you're using VS 2015 x86, you should start a 32bit version of PowerShell/PowerShell ISE as Administrator (won't work if you just' start it without elevated rights, will give you an error) and change ExecutionPolicy to RemoteSigned, like this

```
Set-ExecutionPolicy RemoteSigned
```

and after, restart your Visual Studio. Personally, I don't have it here to test, but think this will fix the error you're getting.